# Is there a verb for "Pass through a hoop?"

Tags: verbs

I am looking for a verb that means "To pass through a hoop", either figuratively or literally. Similar to what dolphins do in those water parks, or to someone having to do something he does not want to because of the situation he is in. 
Is there something similar to what I'm looking for?

Comment: Interesting question--here is an idea.  "Threading the needle" is an idiom that has a literal meaning of passing a thread through the eye of a needle, and, figuratively, one of the meanings is to "skillfully navigate".  I think that you could navigate this idiom so that native speakers could get the figurative meaning and a metaphoric comparison between the dolphin and the thread.  "The dolphin threaded the hoop with distinguished grace." (or through the hoop, but you seemed to want to replace 'through') Now the dolphin has become, metaphorically, the thread passing the eye of a needle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally, we can *jump* or *leap* through hoops.

Figuratively, we can *endure* or *grind* through unwanted situations. [**Endure**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/endure?show=0&t=1398605230) particularly matches your request, because it means to persist in spite of ourselves or some other undesirable effect, like dolphins at a water park. One can also *persevere* (more positive) or *grind* (more negative) through hardship.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase **[jump through hoops](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/jump-through-hoops)** is a figurative expression that means what you are asking about

> Perform a difficult and grueling series of tests at someone else’s request or command:
>   *we had to jump through all sorts of hoops to win accreditation*

Comment: Yeah I know, I just wanted to know if there is a verb I can use instead of the whole expression.

Answer (score 2):

How about "[**traverse**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/traverse)?"

> **traverse**: to move or pass along or through.
>
> "*Those who wish to pursue citizenship should be able to bid their time and [**traverse the hoops**](http://reason.com/blog/2006/04/04/huddled-masses-yearning-to-bre) that they would need to.*"
>
> "*We want the hiring process to happen easily, almost magically, 
>   without having to do research or [traverse hoops](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/styleforstudents/c8.html).*"

Also, consider "[**buck**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buck) through," "[**put on a bold/brave face**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+a+brave+face+on) 
," and "[**make the best of a bad situation**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+the+best+of+a+bad+situation)."

> "*He felt very strange, and decidedly shy; but [**put on a bold face**](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Under_the_Lilacs/Chapter_19), and let nobody guess that, though nearly thirteen, he had never been to school.*"
>
> "*I think we'll try to [**buck through**](http://tomitronics.com/old_buildings/margaretmitchell/apartment1.html) without any 
>   borrowings for a while.*"
>
> "*Paul has made the best of the situation and blossomed in a variety of ways.*"